# Best way to run uninstall string in C#

Tags: c#

I have a code that gets the uninstall string and will need to run it to uninstall a program. Will add arguments to it as well.

Here's an example uninstall string that I will need to run

```
MsiExec.exe /X{002EBFA7-9438-34EA-8BB9-8445758AFE27} /qn /passive /norestart
```

Looking for the most recommended way to convert this to C# code.

Answer (score 0):

```
         var proc = new Process
         {
             StartInfo =
             {
                 FileName = @"msiexec",                        
                 WorkingDirectory = @"C:\wherever",
                 Arguments = @"/qn /passive /norestart"
             }
         }.Start();
```